# I want send user info except password from the express server along with jwt token

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, mern

I'm creating a MERN stack ecommerce application where I want send all user info along with jwt token but except password I'm ok with token part & I know how to send user but i don't know how to exclude the password property while sending the user through res.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvonG.png)

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified Answer -
@prathamesh

You can change the default behavior at the schema definition level using the select attribute of the field:

password: { type: String, select: false }

Then you can pull it in as needed in find and populate calls via field selection as '+password'. For example:

Users.findOne({_id: id}).select('+password').exec(...);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation or select method in the mongoose.

```
const users = await User.find({}, {name: 1, email: 1});
or
const users = await User.find({}).select("name email");
or
const users = await User.aggregate([{"$project": {name: 1, email: 1}}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this way to save all attributes except password in another variable and then I show info.

```js
let {password, ...foundUser} = user.toJSON();
response.setStatus(200).setRes(foundUser);
```